# C++ Boost::thread - kernel: traps general protection

Tags: c++, boost-thread, coredump

My code has worked using an old version of boost 1.49, but it was many years ago. Now i'm using boost 1.67

Edit: My project includes a server/client feature using the same binary.
one the server is started, i can send commands who are received to launch custom process. This is the code showed below.

I identified the line causing the kernel trap:

```
boost::thread th(Temporal::Acquire, transmit, ECONF);
```

- The thread is starting and function in argument is called, but the initiated thread crash instantly.
  I don't understand the "general protection".
- I tried to find more answer from try catch (std::exception &e)
  but it seem's requiring another catcher between... nothing to output.
- Tried to understand the handling for tls_destructor inside libs/thread/src/pthread/thread.cpp, but since i've tested my code by replacing all std to boost only without solve the issue...
- Valgrind show no errors at all.

There is a way to understand the direct termination (without calling join or interrupt) ?

Part to initiate the server socket (from another file), using standard thread, but i don't think that is the source of issue:
Since i started my project, i never got conflict mixing std / boost.

```
coex.push_back(std::thread(Temporal::Listener, ECONF));
```

Server part:

```
#include "lobe.hpp"

#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>

void    Temporal::Acquire(std::string transmit, Json::Value ECONF)
{
    syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "aquired");
    // Temporal::Transcode p(transmit, ECONF);
}

void    Temporal::Listener(Json::Value ECONF)
{
    socklen_t           t;
    std::string         transmit(100, 0);
    int                 PIPE_local, PIPE_remote, len;
    struct sockaddr_un  local, remote;

    int reuseaddr = 1;
    memset(&local, 0, sizeof(local));

    if((PIPE_local = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
        perror("socket");

    if(setsockopt(PIPE_local, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuseaddr, sizeof(reuseaddr)) == -1)
        perror(strerror(errno));

    local.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(local.sun_path, P_SOCK, sizeof(local.sun_path)-1);
    unlink(P_SOCK);
    len = strlen(local.sun_path) + sizeof(local.sun_family);


    if(bind(PIPE_local, (struct sockaddr *)&local, len) == -1)
        perror("bind");

    if(listen(PIPE_local, 5) == -1)
        perror("listen");

    for(;;)
    {
        syslog(LOG_INFO, "inside SOCK");
        int done, com_Listen, com_Talk;
        t = sizeof(remote);
        if((PIPE_remote = accept(PIPE_local, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, &t)) == -1)
            perror("accept");

        done = 0;
        do
        {
            com_Listen = read(PIPE_remote, &transmit[0], 99);
            if(com_Listen <= 0)
            {
                syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "<<-== %s", transmit.c_str());
                if(com_Listen < 0) perror("recv");
                done = 1;

                syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "received");
                boost::thread th(Temporal::Acquire, transmit, ECONF);
            }
        }while(!done);

        close(PIPE_remote);
        break;
    }
    close(PIPE_local);
    unlink(P_SOCK);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    //boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(1));
    Temporal::Listener(ECONF);
}
```

Client part:

The output of systemd coredump:

```
Jun 17 22:37:25 bytewild kernel: traps: EIE[8033] general protection ip:44f59c sp:7fd32bffecb0 error:0 in EIE[400000+233000]
Jun 17 22:37:25 bytewild EIE[7699]: aquired
Jun 17 22:37:25 bytewild systemd[1]: Started Process Core Dump (PID 8034/UID 0).
-- Subject: Unit systemd-coredump@49-8034-0.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel

-- Unit systemd-coredump@49-8034-0.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Jun 17 22:37:25 bytewild systemd-coredump[8041]: Failed to get ACL: Operation not supported
Jun 17 22:37:26 bytewild systemd-coredump[8041]: Process 7699 (EIE) of user 1000 dumped core.

     Stack trace of thread 8033:
     #0  0x000000000044f59c tls_destructor (/data/dev/in/native/projects/eie/build/bin/EIE)
     #1  0x000000000045092a thread_proxy (/data/dev/in/native/projects/eie/build/bin/EIE)
     #2  0x0000000000500155 start_thread (/data/dev/in/native/projects/eie/build/bin/EIE)
     #3  0x00000000005707ff __clone (/data/dev/in/native/projects/eie/build/bin/EIE)

     Stack trace of thread 7700:
     #0  0x0000000000503623 __pthread_cond_timedwait (/data/dev/in/native/projects/eie/build/bin/EIE)
     #1  0x000000000041214b _ZN5boost18condition_variable13do_wait_untilERNS_11unique_lockINS_5mutexEEERKNS_6detail23mono_platform_timepointE (/data/dev/in/native/projects/eie/build/bin/EIE)
     #2  0x000000000040ebe4 _ZN8Temporal8ListenerEN4Json5ValueE (/data/dev/in/native/projects/eie/build/bin/EIE)
     #3  0x000000000041f58e _ZSt13__invoke_implIvPFvN4Json5ValueEEJS1_EET_St14__invoke_otherOT0_DpOT1_ (/data/dev/in/native/projects/eie/build/bin/EIE)
     #4  0x00000000004eb0ef execute_native_thread_routine (/data/dev/in/native/projects/eie/build/bin/EIE)
     #5  0x0000000000500155 start_thread (/data/dev/in/native/projects/eie/build/bin/EIE)
     #6  0x00000000005707ff __clone (/data/dev/in/native/projects/eie/build/bin/EIE)

     Stack trace of thread 7699:
     #0  0x0000000000504a21 __nanosleep (/data/dev/in/native/projects/eie/build/bin/EIE)
     #1  0x000000000056bfea __sleep (/data/dev/in/native/projects/eie/build/bin/EIE)
     #2  0x0000000000406e91 main (/data/dev/in/native/projects/eie/build/bin/EIE)
     #3  0x0000000000506dfa __libc_start_main (/data/dev/in/native/projects/eie/build/bin/EIE)
     #4  0x000000000040790a _start (/data/dev/in/native/projects/eie/build/bin/EIE)
```

Here is a schematic preview of my system to understand the problem:

[image]

Sorry if this is obvious, but i'm stumped. Any clues ?

Comment: I see your thread is created at the end of the block. Looking at this, it appears the thread is destroyed before it completes its work. If you detatch your thread after creating it. does it solve your exception issue?

Comment: Hi Feddy, your'e right, i think so, but adding th.detach() don't solve it.
I've just updated my post to explain a bit more of my project expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code I believe the issue is in this block of code.

```
do
        {
            com_Listen = read(PIPE_remote, &transmit[0], 99);
            if(com_Listen <= 0)
            {
                syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "<<-== %s", transmit.c_str());
                if(com_Listen < 0) perror("recv");
                done = 1;

                syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "received");
                boost::thread th(Temporal::Acquire, transmit, ECONF);
            }
        }while(!done);
```

Specifically, the way you create your `boost::thread`. This is a stack-based variable. As soon as you start your thread its object is destroyed and the `DTor` is called.

I do not have much experience with boost implementation of `thread`, but have used `std::thread` which was largely modeled on boost implementation. Looking at their class [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.destructor) there is an effects section which list the impact of destroying a running thread.

> Effects:
>   - if defined BOOST_THREAD_DONT_PROVIDE_THREAD_DESTRUCTOR_CALLS_TERMINATE_IF_JOINABLE:
>   If the thread is joinable calls detach(), DEPRECATED
>   - if defined BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_THREAD_DESTRUCTOR_CALLS_TERMINATE_IF_JOINABLE:
>   If the thread is joinable calls to std::terminate. Destroys *this.

It looks like the default is to call `terminate()` like `std::thread` does for joinable threads that are destroyed. It looks like the old behavior was to auto detatch those.

**Edit**
Read the destructor documentation for current vs. 1.49.

1.49
Effects:
If *this has an associated thread of execution, calls detach(). Destroys *this.

Now, go read the same code for current(listed above). It states it now defaults to `terminate`

**Edit2**

My suggestion would be to no longer spin up a new thread everytime you receive input from your socket. Instead, I suggest creating a worker queue that has a constant number of background threads. Each time you receive a new event simply add the work object to the queue and one of the background threads will handle the response.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

// Synchrnoized Output
std::mutex stdm;
template <typename T>
void Log(T const& t) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(stdm);
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}

// Task Queue
// Has user provided list of task, which are handled on background threads
template <class T, int N = 4>
class TaskQueue {
    std::deque<T> work;                 // Holds work
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;   // Holds worker threads
    std::mutex m;                       // Holds lock for work container/running
    std::condition_variable cv;         // Worker threads wait on this
    bool running;                       // Inform the task queue if its running

    public:
    // Constructor, spins up worker threads and waits for work
    TaskQueue() : running{true} {
        threads.reserve(N);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            // Build worker threads
            threads.emplace_back([&]() {
                // Normal running before queue destruction
                while (running) {
                    {
                        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(
                            m);
                        cv.wait(lk, [&] {
                            return !running ||
                                   work.size() != 0;
                        });

                        // Extract work && Update work
                        // Queue
                        T t = std::move(work.front());
                        work.pop_front();

                        // Release lock before
                        // performing work
                        lk.unlock();

                        // Peform work
                        t();
                    }
                }

                // Empty Queue on destrucrtion
                bool hasMoreWork = true;
                do {
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
                    if ((hasMoreWork = work.size() > 0)) {
                        // Manage Work
                        T t = std::move(work.front());
                        work.pop_front();

                        // has more?
                        hasMoreWork = work.size() > 0;

                        // release lock
                        lk.unlock();

                        // perform work
                        t();
                    }
                } while (hasMoreWork);
            });
        }
    }

    ~TaskQueue() {
        // Inform queue its closing
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m);
            running = false;
        }

        // Inform all threads of change
        cv.notify_all();

        // Clear out remainings objects
        int workObjects = 0;
        bool queueCleared = false;
        do {
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(m);
                queueCleared = (workObjects = work.size()) == 0;
                Log("Queue Has Remaining: " +
                    std::to_string(workObjects));
            }

            // Give worker threads time to work
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(
                std::chrono::milliseconds(250));
        } while (!queueCleared);

        // If any threads are still processing, join them to the current
        // thread or else terminate() is called
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if (threads[i].joinable()) threads[i].join();
        }
    }

    template <class... Args>
    void emplace_back(Args&&... args) {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m);
            if (running)
                work.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
        cv.notify_one();
    }
};

// The actual task that performs work
struct Task {
    std::string transmit;
    std::string ECONF;

    Task() : transmit(""), ECONF("") {}
    Task(std::string&& t, std::string&& e) : transmit(t), ECONF(e) {}

    void operator()() {
        std::thread::id tid = std::this_thread::get_id();
        std::hash<std::thread::id> hasher;
        Log(transmit + ':' + ECONF +
            " Process Time: 500ms One Thread: " +
            std::to_string(hasher(tid)));

        // Fake work to consume thread
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    }
};

int main() {
    TaskQueue<Task> tp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i) {
        // Add work
        tp.emplace_back("Transmit: " + std::to_string(i),
                "ECONF: " + std::to_string(i));

        // Simulate waiting for the next event from socket
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(25));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There is a good number of improvments that can be made, but this should give you a rough overview. Hope this helps.

Comment: yeah, i know those requirement from std::thread, but i have not changed my code since boost 1.49 (5 years ago) and now at 1.67, and i had never used the .join() to terminate a boost thread. Even, when i try to terminate it manually, the same coredump is generated.

Comment: @MTroy The default behavior was changed. If you look at the documentation from 1.49 it states the default behavior is to call `detatch`. If you look at the recent documentation its to call `terminate`. Your code has not changed, boost implementation of `thread` has.

Comment: Indeed ! But that mean i cannot do what i want with this change ?
I need to send many command to be threaded in parallel. If the boost:thread is now terminate instantly, how to parallelize each thread ?
detach() is not working, it crash anyway

Comment: Before you detach make sure the thread is joinable. Or use a worker queue. I’m not around my pc, but I’ll update my answer later with an example.

Comment: th.joinable() say "true", but detach() still not applicable. Do you think forgot boost threading and working with std pthread only is a better idea ?

Comment: Thanks for your advise, i'm currently trying to recode my work to use boost::asio services. Not finished to write, but hope will be a good analogy and not decreasing perf (the whole project is using static libraries).

Comment: @MTroy Added an alternative. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: sorry for late (working a lot), your exemple looks very good to a abord my issue !  I've only on question about it. I see that emplace_back provide "va_arg" (instead of push_back), but is it possible to define "task structure" able to take any type of data, like function without know it's type before receiving ?
On my side, i found a substitute working solution using boost::asio and io_context guard work, but you concept will be usefull to the next part of my program requiring a bigger amount of queries. The actual issue need only 3 or 4 client max.

Comment: i found this : https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/1298d74
It's similar using asio, but without mutex management. Do you think i can make it more adaptive ?